# Sample Function R language

Tags: r

How do you write this?
        Suppose you have a population of 800 people, where 300 are Democrat, 400 are Republican, and 100 are Independent.
            How many Democrats would you expect to get in a simple random sample of 10 people from this population?

I wrote

```
D<-1:300
I<-1:100
R<-1:400
Population<-c("D","I","R")
table(sample(Population,size=10, replace= TRUE))
```

but apparently it is not right.I am a little confused.

I found my answer, Instead of assigning a number to the letter d, i and r, just count how many d, i and r.

it will be like this

pop<-c(rep("D",500),rep("R",300),rep("I",200))
samplepop<-(sample(pop,10,replace=FALSE))

Comment: This is a statistics question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Create the population:

```
> population <- c(rep('Democrat', 300), rep('Independent', 100), rep('Republican', 400))
```

And, per Richard Scriven's suggestion, sample the population a few thousand times:

```
>  sapply(1:10000, function(i) {sum(sample(population, size = 10, replace=TRUE) == 'Democrat')})
```

Comment: You may want `replicate` rather than `sapply`.

Comment: Thanks! I thought in the wrong direction trying to make democrat a number instead i should just count how many d's there is.pop<-c(rep("D",500),rep("R",300),rep("I",200))
samplepop<-(sample(pop,10,replace=FALSE))

Answer (score 0):

You can add a vector of probability weights to your analysis.

```
Population<-c("D","I","R")
t = table(sample(Population,size=10, replace= TRUE, prob = c(0.375, 0.125, 0.5)))

> t

D I R 
3 1 6
```

Answer (score 0):

When you extract 10 people out of a 800 people population, you have `choose(800,10)` different ways to extract them, where `choose` is the number of combinations. If you want to know for instance how many ways you have of extracting `N` Democrats, you obtain `choose(500,10-N)*choose(300,N)` since you have `10-N` non Democrats out of 500 people and `N` Democrats out of 300 people. To obtain the probability you just divide the two values above. In general:

```
      N<-0:10
      probs<-(choose(500,10-N)*choose(300,N))/choose(800,10)
      #calculate the average number of Democrats
      sum(probs*N)
      #[1] 3.75
      #calculate the standard deviation
      sqrt(sum(probs*N^2)-3.75^2)
      #[1] 1.522284
```

The `probs` vector contains the probability of extracting 0,1,2,...,10 Democrats.
This is the exact solution to the problem and agrees with the proposed simulations.